# Why is my file throwing an error on execution?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am getting an error when I try to execute a file using the command `node database.ts`
Can anyone tell me what the issue is with my syntax?

The file looks like:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';

export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    database : "zemit",
    dialect : "postgres",
    username : "postgres",
    password : "postgres",
    host : "localhost",
    port : 5432
});
sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
 console.log("Connected to DB");
})
.catch((err) => {
 console.log(err);
})
```

The error says:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11?[39m
```

Comment: What version of node.js are you running?

Comment: version 10.15.3

Comment: I just upgraded to 12.13.0 but I get a new error which I posted above.

Comment: Try giving your file a `.mjs` file extension to indicate it's a Javascript module file, not the older style .js file or set a `module` file type in package.json.  See https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules for details.  You may also need the `--experimental-modules` command line option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node` runtime system does not support run a `Typescript file` file as a `.js` file. If you are working with `Typescript`, you have to transpile your `.ts` files to `.js` file with command `tsc` (require Typescript installed), then you run your generated `.js` file with `node database.js` command (instead of `node database.ts`)

Or you can use [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) - TypeScript execution and REPL for node.js, then you can "run" a `.ts` file directly, with `ts-node database.ts` command.

Answer (score 1):

Just replaced all the "imports" with "requires".

I had similar issue, searched online but didn`t got any solution.

Then I replaced import with require and it worked.